# JavaFX 2.0 Toolbar FXML

Tags: toolbar, javafx, javafx-2, fxml, pane

Q: Help me identify what's causing the error, and hopefully getting the toolbar to work.

I'm trying to take the FXML-version from this page:
Difference in my java-class from link[1](http://fxexperience.com/2012/02/customized-segmented-toolbar-buttons/):

1. It's not a main-class.
2. It does not extend Application but HBox or anything if it would work.
3. Error message: "javafx.fxml.LoadException: javafx.fxml.JavaFXBuilder$ObjectBuilder does not have a default property."
4. Well, here the class is:

   public class MainWindow implements Initializable {
       private  ResourceBundle rb;

   ```
   final static boolean RIGHT_TO_LEFT = false;

      //FXML ATTRIBUTES
       @FXML
       private OverviewTab owContent;
       @FXML
       private StatisticsTab statisticsContent;
       @FXML
       private SettingsTab settingsContent;
       @FXML
       private Polygon dock_bottom;
       @FXML
       private TabPane tabpane; 
       @FXML
       private Tab owTab;
       @FXML
       private Tab statisticsTab;
       @FXML
       private Tab settingsTab;
       @FXML
       private Button helpButton;
       @FXML
       private Button updateButton;
       @FXML private Button task;


   /**
    * Create the application.
    */
    @Override
       public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        this.rb = rb;
           // Adding Swing style of custom Listener
           tabpane.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Tab>() {
               @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Tab> observableValue, Tab oldTab, Tab newTab) {
                   if(newTab.equals(owTab)){

                   }
               }
             });
        //statisticsContent.addListener(this);
       owTab.setText(rb.getString("overviewTab_headline"));
       statisticsTab.setText(rb.getString("statisticsTab_headline"));
       settingsTab.setText(rb.getString("settingsTab_headline"));
    }
   ```

   }

Comment: Post the content of FXML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author of the tutorial you are referencing, mentions the error and provides solution to it in his next post/tutorial. See [ToolBar in FXML No Longer Requires tag](http://fxexperience.com/2012/02/toolbar-in-fxml-no-longer-requires-tag/). I think you are facing the same problem.

Comment: Yeah, but if i'm not wrong he uses javafx 2.1. I'm limited to using 2.0. But I finally got it working.. barely! Thanks for comment though!